# How to understand this algebraic contradiction and relate to definition of complex numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Using the following identities:

$x^b \cdot x^a = x^{b+a}$  (#1)

Example: $100^1 \cdot 100^{-1} = 100^{1-1} = 1 $

$(yz)^c =y^c \cdot z^c $   (#2)

Example: $16^{3/2} \cdot \sqrt{9}=16^1 \cdot 16^{1/2} \cdot 9^{1/2} = 16 \cdot (16 \cdot 9)^{1/2} = 16 \cdot 144^{1/2} = 16\cdot 12 = 192$

Now taking $\sqrt{-4} \cdot \sqrt{-4} $

We get $(-4)^1 = -4$ by using (#1) but $\sqrt{(-4)(-4)}=\sqrt{16} = \pm4$ by using (#2). How to explain that and relate this "contradiction" to the imaginary number $i$ where $\sqrt{i^2} = i $ and not $\pm i$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some limitations built into exponentiation. The base number and exponent cannot be just anything:

- If we limit ourselves to $y \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$, then $x^y$ makes sense for any $x \in \Bbb C$.
- If $y \in \Bbb Z$, then $x^y$ makes sense for any $x \in \Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$.
- If $y \in \Bbb R$, then $x^y$ makes sense only for $x \in \Bbb R, x > 0$.
- If $y \in \Bbb C$, then $x^y$ makes sense only for $x = e$.

So you see, the more freely you're allowed to choose $y$, the more restrictive the choices of $x$ becomes. In your case, with the exponent being $y = 1/2$, we are only allowed to use *positive reals* for base. Otherwise the exponentiation rules (such as $x^{yz} = (x^y)^z$ and $x^{y+z} = x^yx^z$) will get you into exactly the kind of problems that you have discovered.

For instance, $i$ is not defined as $\sqrt{-1}$, really. It's defined by $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: For the last bullet, why should it make sense only if $x=e$? Check "imaginary exponent" on the link.... http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_22.html#Ch22-S6

Comment: Just to be sure $y \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$ reads : "y belongs to the set of all natural numbers excluding 0". Correct?

Comment: @aniket Because, by using the natural logarithm, $10^i$ could be $-0.668 + 0.744i$, but it could _also_ be that times $e^{2\pi n}$ for any natural $n$. What has been done in those notes is to make a _branch choice_. It is not a choice that can be done in a consistent way, but you will never discover that through that table because the powers are only along the imaginary axis. The problem appears when you try to assume that the total piower changes continuously as the exponent moves along the unit circle in the complex plane. And to snoram, yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @Arthur : There is also a sense for example for $x^\frac{1}{3}$ with $x<0$ , because $x\mapsto x^3$ is a one-to-one function.

Comment: @Baloown But then what about $x^{2/6}$, which by all accounts _should_ be the same? I agree that you're allowed to do $\sqrt[3]{x}$, but $x^{1/3}$ gets you trouble.

Comment: @Arthur : Yes you're right, I should have used this symbol and not $x^\frac{1}{3}.$ Thank you.

Comment: Arthur: Actually the exponent in my example was $y = 1/2$... not $-1/2$

Comment: @snoram Fixed. It doesn't change anything, though.

Answer (score 0):

The square root of a positive real number $x$ is by definition the only positive real number $y$ such as $y^2=x$. Thus there is no $+/-$ to add in front of your last $4$.

Comment: Did you mean square root?

Comment: @Aniket : thanks, edited that.

Comment: Of course, my mistake. Yet, it doesn't take the "contradiction" away... am I allowed to edit the original post?

Comment: @snoram : Yes of course !

Comment: Wait a minute, now that I come back to the problem it is not obvious to me that $\sqrt{16}$ is not $\pm 4$... and it seems I am not the only one confused about this: https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/square-root.html

Comment: Here things are somewhat cleared up: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/imaginary_complex_precalc/i_precalc/v/i-as-the-principal-root-of-1-a-little-technical